# Flutter: Navigation drawer with expansion tile

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I`m trying to build a navigation drawer with expansion tile, when i click on the header it collapse and vice versa
but when i set the the drawer header as a child of ExpansionTile, original header padding is lost

[image]

```
 Widget _buildDrawer() {
return Drawer(
    child: ExpansionTile(
  title: UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.deepPurple),
    accountName: Text("Mohamed Ali"),
    accountEmail: Text("mohamed.ali6996@hotmail.com"),
    currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
      child: Text("M"),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    ),
  ),
  children: <Widget>[
    ListTile(
      title: Text("page one"),
      trailing: Icon(Icons.android),
      onTap: () => _onSelectedItem(0),
    ),
    ListTile(
      title: Text("page two"),
      trailing: Icon(Icons.accessible),
      onTap: () => _onSelectedItem(1),
    ),
    Divider(),
    ListTile(
      title: Text("Log out"),
      trailing: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
    ),
  ],
  initiallyExpanded: false,
)
```

);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the header takes the place of the first tile in the `ExpansionTile`.

One possible solution is to use a `Stack` and tweak the content with an `Align` so the expansion icon is at the bottom of the header.

Changing the color of the expanding icon may not work for you. There is a reported [issue here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23053) for which I have already submitted a [PR here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/23118). Don't know when it will land in master.

```
_buildDrawer(BuildContext context) {
  ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
  return Drawer(
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.indigo),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 120.0,
          left: 0.0,
          right: 0.0,
          child: Theme(
            data: theme.copyWith(
              textTheme: theme.textTheme.copyWith(
                subhead: theme.textTheme.subhead.copyWith(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
              ),
              accentColor: Colors.white,
              unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.grey,
              iconTheme: theme.iconTheme.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
              dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
            ),
            child: ExpansionTile(
              title: Align(
                heightFactor: 0.4,
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.transparent),
                  accountName: Text("Mohamed Ali"),
                  accountEmail: Text("mohamed.ali6996@hotmail.com"),
                  currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                    child: Text("M"),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  title: Text("page one"),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.android),
                  onTap: () => {},
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text("page two"),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.accessible),
                  onTap: () => {},
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 1.0,
                  color: Color(0xFFDDDDDD),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text("Log out"),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
                ),
              ],
              initiallyExpanded: false,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )
}
```

Comment: It worked well, but i think it needs more customization. for example, the arrow is in the middle of the header and i can not change its position or color, and most importantly, i need to show another list tiles when its collapsed.

Comment: Of course it needs more customization. I provided a possible solution to make it work but it's your job to adapt it to your project.

Comment: I will accept your answer as this is a working solution and the customization i want can not be achieved at the moment.thnx

Comment: Well, you are right that it does not cover everything. I will try to add some tweaks when I get home.

Comment: I have edited the answer. It is difficult to know exactly what you want to achieve but you can see that the possibilities are limitless.